# display two dimensional coordinate map in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need a way to convert a coordinate map detailing a maze of 1s in a field of 0s into a set of plotted lines in pyplot.
To illustrate, I need to convert this

```
maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

into

```
 plt.plot([4,4,4,4,4,3,2],[0,1,2,3,4,4,4])
 plt.plot([3,4,4,4],[6,6,7,8])
```

such that if i need to, i can change the coordinate map and it will reflect the changes in the plotting.

Comment: What will you do if the 1s are *not* arranged in neat lines? What if they are on diagonals? How about if they form a cross shape? Do you actually need to figure out "where the lines are", or are you just trying to *display the corresponding image*?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd be better off with an `imshow`:

```
plt.imshow(maze)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: to give a little more context.
after plotting out the shape of the maze, the intention is to afterwards plot out a set of coordinates pumped out by an algorithm that I'm testing that plots a course throughout the maze.
so for example solution to this maze is in the following format

`path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]`

is it still possible to display both the path and the maze using imshow?